# What's the best architecture for a hybrid mobile application?

Tags: mobile, backbone.js, cordova, requirejs, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm developing a big hybrid mobile application (PhoneGap/HTML5), that have to contain a lot of views and server calls. After some searches on the Internet, I found that I can organize my code with RequireJS, Backbone and jQuery Mobile. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.appliness.com/getting-started-with-html-mobile-application-development-using-jquery-mobile-requirejs-and-backbonejs), which is very helpful, but I'm not really satisfied...

The problem is that each view is loaded by RequireJS when I press a link or a button, and it replaces the content of the previous view... I mean, the whole HTML code between `<body></body>` is replaced by the content of the new view. And if I decide not to replace the previous code and append the new code, there is a risk that the application may not be very user-friendly.

I have thought to separate all the views and put them in multiple HTML files, and write a Javascript that loads all the HTML files and appends them to the main body, but I don't know if this is a good practice and if my application will be very user-friendly. Here is an example of how I thought to organize my code :

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- ... -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Here will be added the content of all the other HTML files -->
    </body>
</html>


<!-- homeView.html -->
<div data-role="header" data-theme="f">
    <h1 data-i18n="sections.home.title"></h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
    <h1 data-i18n="sections.home.welcome"></h1>
</div>


<!-- otherView.html -->
<div data-role="header" data-theme="f">
    <h1 data-i18n="sections.otherView.title"></h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
    <p data-i18n="sections.otherView.content"></p>
</div>
```

What do you guys think about it ? Does anyone have a better solution ? My aim is to build a strong, fluid and maintainable application.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, Backbone gives you finer-grained control over how you want to display your views: you should be able to replace only parts of your view without having to choose between "replace everything" and "append to the current HTML".

It's generally a good idea to break up your views in several HTML files (especially given that you can use templating, e.g. with Underscore), but I don't think you should load everything at once if that's what you mean.

I'll give you a more detailed example if you feel that it would answer to your question, but basically if you press a link or a button you're able to catch that event and do whatever you want with it, from replacing the whole view to just changing one single element.

EDIT: I'll answer the rest of your question here.
First you should have a look at http://backboneboilerplate.com/, it's a pretty good demonstration of how to structure a backbone application. In particular, they use a view manager (vm.js) which handles creating the views.

Using something like this allows you to keep in memory the last instance of a view. For example, when you click on a news item you'd have your router navigating to /news/item/xx, and you'd use the view manager to create a news item and fill the model with localStorage (if you have already fetched the content) or by polling the server.
Looking at the view manager code, you can have something like this:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'events'
], function($, _, Backbone, Events){
  var views = {};
  var create = function (context, name, View, options) {
    if(typeof views[name] !== 'undefined') {
      if (name === "homeview") {
        views[name].reinit(); // <==== re-initialize your view
        return views[name];
      }
      else {
        views[name].undelegateEvents();
        if(typeof views[name].clean === 'function') {
          views[name].clean();
        }
      }
    }
    var view = new View(options);
    views[name] = view;
    if(typeof context.children === 'undefined'){
      context.children = {};
      context.children[name] = view;
    } else {
      context.children[name] = view;
    }
    Events.trigger('viewCreated');
    return view;
  };


  return {
    create: create
  };
});
```

That way, the view manager keeps your home view in memory, and re-initialize and returns it whenever you come back to it (I called .reinit() but it could be any custom function to reset your view to the state you previously saved and render it)

Comment: Let's consider that I have a news application. In the home view, there will be a lot of news retrieved from a server, and using a menu panel, I can open the settings view. And when I close this view, I want to get back to the home view with the same state as I left it (I suppose I have scroller down...). How can I do this using Backbone (and Underscore) and separating the HTML code of the 2 views ?

Comment: By "state" you mean you want to keep the news items fetched from the server, and for example the cursor position if the user has scrolled down?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want :)

Comment: See the updated reply: one way of doing that is by using a view manager to keep the last instance of your view in memory, and have that instance store the parameters that you want (e.g. where the user had scrolled) when you switch to another view

Comment: Thanks, I'm analysing the backbone boilerplate source code, I think it can be helpful :)